Pytesseract permission error for some images
I am using pytesseract to classify a set of images. it works for many of them but in some I got an error similar to this one:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[18], line 51
     41 list_of_prefixes = {'axial':{'LE':{'aged':'E',
     42                                     'unaged':'C'},
     43                               'BE':{'aged':'D',
   (...)
     47                     'props':'A',
     48                     }
     50 if __name__ == '__main__':
---> 51     main(document_path = document_path,
     52          excel_file=excel_file,
     53          list_of_prefixes=list_of_prefixes,
     54          dpi=dpi,
     55          table_style=table_style,
     56          includes_dict=includes_dict,
     57          delete_temp=True,
     58          nbr_report_pages=num_report_pages)

Cell In[17], line 18
     16 check = [filename for filename in os.listdir(axial_pdfs_folder) if filename.endswith(".pdf")]
     17 if check:
---> 18     mod_doc, TOC_vals, new_cum_axial = insert_plates(doc_path=document_path,
     19                                                             axial_pdfs_folder=axial_pdfs_folder,
     20                                                             props_df=props_df,
...
     71     # Clean up the temporary file
     72     if os.path.exists(temp_image_path):
---> 73         os.remove(temp_image_path)

PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\Users\\V34FD~1.MED\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpzg2vxncf.png'

`
This is the portion of my code that does the classification:
`
# Classify single axial capacity plate
def classify_axial_img(classification_dict, includes_dict, platform, analysis_case,
                        plate_number, image_path,  manual_classification=None):
    try:
        img_org = cv2.imread(image_path)

        # Try with original image
        extracted_text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img_org)
        check = False

        for col in includes_dict.keys():
            if includes_dict[col]['keyword'] in extracted_text:
                classification_dict[platform][analysis_case][col][0].append(plate_number)
                classification_dict[platform][analysis_case][col][1].append(image_path)
                return classification_dict

        # Try with preprocessings
        if not check:
            for preprocessing in preprocessings:
                preprocessed_img = apply_preprocessing(preprocessing, img_org)
                extracted_text = pytesseract.image_to_string(preprocessed_img)

                for col in includes_dict.keys():
                    if includes_dict[col]['keyword'] in extracted_text:
                        classification_dict[platform][analysis_case][col][0].append(plate_number)
                        classification_dict[platform][analysis_case][col][1].append(image_path)
                        return classification_dict
                    
        return classification_dict
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print('Could not classify image {}.'.format(image_path))
        return classification_dict

`
my version of tesseract is 5.3.3, Windows 10
I've tried deleting the temporal folder before runing the code to see if there is any temporal file that was not deleted.
This is an example of how my apply_preprocessing function looks like:
# get grayscale image
if preprocessing == 'grayscale':
    return cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


traceback required. [mre]

Thank you Christoph R. Unfortunately, the loop where this function is used in my code,sometimes doesn't show the error and executes properly until the end. I've been trying to provide more details to reproduce the error but it hasn't appeared in my last run that takes around 7hrs to complete. I'll try to update the post if I can catch the error again. It seems to me that this error occurs because tesseract opens a temp file when classifying the image and when it passes to the next image it doesn't delete the previous temp or somehow interferes with another temp file that is being created
